# PHP variable question

Tags: php, variables

**This works:**

```
$customerBox = mysql_query("MY SQL STATEMENT HERE");  
$boxRow = mysql_fetch_array($customerBox);  

$customerBox = mysql_query("MY SQL STATEMENT AGAIN");
while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($customerBox)) {
      foreach ($item as $columnName => $value) {
          if (empty($value)) {
               print $columnName;
          }
      }
}
```

**This does not:**

```
$customerBox = mysql_query("MY SQL STATEMENT HERE");  
$boxRow = mysql_fetch_array($customerBox);  

while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($customerBox)) {
      foreach ($item as $columnName => $value) {
          if (empty($value)) {
               print $columnName;
          }
      }
}
```

Why?  I guess I don't understand how variables work yet.

Comment: does the query return more than 1 row?  If not, that's why the "error" exists (`$boxRow` takes the first row, and there are no more left for the next call to fetch)...

Comment: "MY SQL STATEMENT HERE" is different than "MY SQL STATEMENT AGAIN". duh.

Comment: what mysql query are you using

Comment: ircmaxell - only 1 row is returned.  I'm not sure I understand though. Doesn't $customerBox equal the same thing regardless of what is fetched from it?

Comment: rajmohan - SELECT * FROM box WHERE customer_id='$logOptions_id'

Comment: Doesn't work = nothing is printed.

Comment: This may have more to do with the mysql_fetch_array() than your variable. What happens when you put `mysql_data_seek ( $customerBox , 0 );` before the while loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because since the query returns one row, there's nothing left to fetch.

the `mysql_fetch_*` functions fetch the *current* row and then advance the row pointer to the next one.  If the current row doesn't exist, it returns false.  So on your second call to `mysql_fetch_assoc`, the pointer is on the 2nd row, but that row doesn't exist so your loop isn't executed.  You have two options:

Good:  Remove the `while` loop, and change `foreach` to use `$boxRow` instead:

```
foreach ($boxRow as $columnName => $value) {
    //...
}
```

Ok: Rewind MySQL's row pointer using [`mysql_data_seek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php):

```
$boxRow = mysql_fetch_array($customerBox);
mysql_data_seek($customerBox, 0);
while(...){
```

Answer (score 1):

This may have more to do with the mysql_fetch_array() than your variable. Try to put this:

```
mysql_data_seek ( $customerBox , 0 );
```

right before the while loop starts. I am curious to see the result.

Comment: +1 since you did beat me to it (even though you had deleted your answer right after I posted my)...

Answer (score 0):

$customerBox = mysql_query("MY SQL STATEMENT HERE");
$boxRow = mysql_fetch_array($customerBox);

while($item = mysql_fetch_field($customerBox)) {
      foreach ($item as $columnName => $value) {
          if (empty($value)) {
               print $columnName;
          }
      }
}